# Convert cloned template into useable element

Tags: javascript, html

I don't really understand why I cannot use a cloned template element as is. I can do some things but not others.

**HTML**

```
<template id="temp">
   <button name="reset">Reset</button>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
let template = document.getElementById('temp');
let element = template.content.cloneNode(true);
element.querySelector('[name="reset"]').innerHTML = "Reset?"; // works
element.id = "myid"; // nothing
element.setAttribute("id", "myid"); // error
```

I feel like I have half an element here....

```js
let template = document.getElementById('temp');
let element = template.content.cloneNode(true);
element.querySelector('[name="reset"]').innerHTML = "Reset?"; // works
element.id = "myid"; // nothing
element.setAttribute("id", "myid"); // error
```

```html
<template id="temp">
       <button name="reset">Reset</button>
    </template>
```

Comment: There is no nested element inside the button.  The `element` is going to be the button already.  Unless I'm misreading this.

Comment: Sonofa. Yeah .. yeah.....

Comment: No that's not right, the cloned content is not the button.  logging the template.content the button is some child of it.  So it may be a document fragment at that point

Comment: Yes it is a fragment. My real scenario is a table row, but don't worry. What you said made me realize the issue. Thanks.

Comment: `var button = element.querySelector('button'); button.id = 'thing'`